# How to store numeric data for nextjs/react website? (csv file? backend api call? download from a different server?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js

I have a nextjs site and would like to display a chart on it. Where should I put the data for this chart? The options I see are:

1. Create a csv and put it in the public folder and load it from there
2. Create a csv and put it on a different server so my site can download it from there
3. Create a graphql (or other api) call on my backend which could send this data

I guess for frequently updating data 3. is the best option right? What about for static data?

Answer (score 0):

For data you will seldomly be updating you could add a csv and import the data as a Json file on application build using something like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson).

This is probably the best solution for data you update often, but you will need to build your frontend application (Your next.js app) every time you update the csv.  This is really not such a problem if you have a working CI/CD. (check out vercel for next.js if you havent)